# How to maintain session timeout in core java application?

Tags: java, session, design-patterns

I know there are different mechanism to maintain session in java web application like, in servlet

1. URL rewritting
2. Hidden form fields
3. Cookies
4. HTTP Session

But I don't have any idea how we can maintain any session in core java application (i.e. Standalone application). So can anyone please help me out from finding some of my question,

How to maintain a timeout session for a specific user in standalone application? Please try to give some code for explanation

Comment: You don't really need session timeout in standalone application. That's why they are standalone. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to time out the user who is more then for specific time without any update..

Comment: And you want to do that because...

Comment: used by the clerks of the backoffice of banks

Comment: Well, define inactivity time first: By not performing any action at all, by not even moving the mouse inside the applicaton, by not pressing any key... You have to have in mind that a standalone application **IS NOT** a web application at all, so first define what you really need to address.

Comment: thanks for help, but can u give me little code also, I will be obliged to you

Comment: What code could I provide if I don't understand your problem. What worries me more is that you don't understand your problem.

Comment: I got some idea from your hint thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [InactivityListener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/) in

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/

There are times when you may want to monitor your application for inactivity. Maybe you want to log out a user after a certain time interval. This requirement can be broken down into two main steps. We will need to:

listen for events at the application level
track the time interval between these events

Whenever the time interval between events exceeds our inactivity threshhold we will then invoke the inactivity Action.

Answer (score 0):

http://pdf.coreservlets.com/Session-Tracking.pdf

Please refer bove link. In that PDF you will get good example at the end of the book.

By default, session-tracking is based on cookies that are stored in the browser’s memory,
not written to disk. Thus, unless the servlet explicitly reads the incoming
JSESSIONID cookie, sets the maximum age and path, and sends it back out, quitting
the browser results in the session being broken: the client will not be able to access
the session again. The problem, however, is that the server does not know that the
browser was closed and thus the server has to maintain the session in memory until
the inactive interval has been exceeded.

// In Servlet
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
            HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long expiryTime = currTime + session.getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000;
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("serverTime", "" + currTime);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            httpResp.addCookie(cookie);
            if (httpReq.getRemoteUser() != null) {
                cookie = new Cookie("sessionExpiry", "" + expiryTime);
            } else {
                cookie = new Cookie("sessionExpiry", "" + currTime);
            }
            cookie.setPath("/");
            httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
            filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }